# No module named error

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

I encountered an error, while i am practicing Login with authentication-pyramid framework - "**init**.py" as below,

```
File __init__.py, line 4, in <module>
from .security import groupfinder
ImportError: No module named 'myproject.security'
```

I have placed security.py file inside myproject folder. but 
when I changed import as,

```
from security import groupfinder
```

web app successfully runs.

My question is why .security throws error as "No module named 'myproject.security" while security.py is still inside myproject folder. Is that ".security" and "security" is different. What that operator "." corresponds to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing files, Python uses the `.` notation to indicate submodules. In this case, since your two files are in the same folder (and since you are running inside the `myproject` namespace), there is no need to indicate a subdomain.

If you had two modules, `myproject` and `myproject2`, and wanted to import a file from `myproject2` into `myproject`, then you would need to use this notation.

In all cases, however, importing `.anything` without being preceded with a module, such as `myproject2.anything` will cause an error. Hopefully this helps, I'm not great at explaining this stuff.